# How can I give special character to php from html without displaying it in website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to give some representation to some links in html so that those representation could be used to release links according to that representation.

I have created some of the link, but when you click those links it will show a modal to fill the from and those users are given links whose details match to my database. But, the problem is that, I am not able to give specified links.

This is my html code:

```
<td>Assignment 2</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="gitdownload g1"  title="Click to download">Zip file</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>2.18 MB</td>
                    <td>June 21, 2019</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Assignment 3</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="gitdownload g2" title="Click to download">Zip file</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>2.65 MB</td>
                    <td>June 27, 2019</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Assignment 4</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="gitdownload g3"  title="Click to download">Zip file</a>
                    </td>
```

This is my js code for modal:

```
        document.querySelector('.g2').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';
        });

        document.querySelector('.g3').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';
        });

        document.querySelector('.g4').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';
        });
```

This is my php:

```
if($user){
                if($user['firstname'] === $firstname && $user['lastname'] === $lastname && $user['std_id'] === $std_id){

                    ob_start(); 

                    $url = 'https://google.com';    

                    while (ob_get_status()) 
                    {
                        ob_end_clean();
                    }

                    header( "Location: $url" );  

                }
```

As in the following codes.. main problem is that either I click Assignment 2 or 3 or 4, after authorization, every link(ie, Assignment 2, Assignment 3, Assignment 4) are open to https://google.com . Here what I want is that when I click Assignment 2, it should open different link.

If I cannot explain it properly please ask.. I would appreciate it.

Comment: `But, the problem is that, I am not able to give specified links.` Is this why your hyperlinks have no `href` attribute referring to the correct zip file? How exactly are you going to send the zip file to the user if you do not know where the file is? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Shilly Yes you are correct.. but if I give links there then how could I protect them.. I want links to be add in php..

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your problem is you are getting the same url:https://google.com when you click on any hyperlink Assignment2 3 or 4. If I am correct so the problem is you are using a variable $url and you have already set this to https://google.com and you are using header to relocate page. This is same as header( "Location:https://google.com" ) every time you click on any link. The thing you have to do is to dynamically change url(value of variable) link and then use header function you will always get associated link on click.

Comment: @FAWAD SIDDIQUI  I got you point but how can php know which link user clicked so that php can send specified links..

Comment: Dear, you have to three ways to do this. I will explain them one by one.
First Way : The first way is you can fit your .js  model in a form and submit this form with the corresponding link. As you will submit this link as hidden type in php you can get this link by simply global array POST. Now you will check the condition through isset() method. If form is submitted you can modify your $url by assigning it simply $_POST method. and you will get new url you can use simply header function.

Comment: Second Way: Although first way was workable, it has a problem. It wil refresh you webpage when you submit form. The best way is to use AJAX. AJAX can be us to submit data dynamically. You give an ajax can with query variable.

Third Way: You can also use JQuery methtod of ajax to call for link data. Just learn basics of this method it's easy you can learn and implement it. W3 School is one of the source to learn it. 

You can use any of the ways discussed above.

Comment: thanks for your help.. I will learn basics of ajax and jquery and will let you know if I am able to do so or not.